# Adding a class to a psuedo :before element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onchange, pseudo-element

I am trying to add an image within my `:before` element with an `change` function. What I am doing is wrapping a label around the `#signupCheck` to work as a checkbox input. I added a `console.log` statement to my change event and it isn't running, so I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone see anything that could be causing this to not work?

```js
$('#proposal-check-wrap').on('change', function() {
  $('#signupCheck:before').addClass('active');
  console.log("change worked");
});
```

```css
#proposal-check {
 display: none;
}
#signupCheck:before {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #858585;
 background: #333333;
 content: '';
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 10px 0 2.4%;
}
#signupCheck:before.active {
 background-image: url("https://lh3.ggpht.com/OHBD2vcwNk80-q1P84NDmYjnwNmD8R-FjJagxvfcZhGHeRx6dNFX12afBL4e88nCra0=w300");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}
#signupCheck {
 color: #858585;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="proposal-check" id="proposal-check-wrap">
  <p id="signupCheck">Sign me up</p>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="proposal-check">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are incorrectly binding the event handler to the label `#proposal-check-wrap` instead of the checkbox `#proposal-check`.
2. Pseudo-elements cannot have attributes.

The originating element *can* have a class, so attach the class to that element instead, and style its pseudo-element based on the class. In other words, instead of `#signupCheck:before.active`, apply the rule to `#signupCheck.active:before`:

```js
$('#proposal-check').on('change', function() {
  $('#signupCheck').addClass('active');
  console.log("change worked");
});
```

```css
#proposal-check {
 display: none;
}
#signupCheck:before {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #858585;
 background: #333333;
 content: '';
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 10px 0 2.4%;
}
#signupCheck.active:before {
 background-image: url("https://lh3.ggpht.com/OHBD2vcwNk80-q1P84NDmYjnwNmD8R-FjJagxvfcZhGHeRx6dNFX12afBL4e88nCra0=w300");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}
#signupCheck {
 color: #858585;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="proposal-check" id="proposal-check-wrap">
  <p id="signupCheck">Sign me up</p>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="proposal-check">
```

Your two `:before` rules have unequal dimensions by the way. Just a note in case this is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.

1. Your change listener needs to be on the input itself.
2. You can't manipulate a psuedo element like that. Instead you should add the class to the element (no psuedo mentioned in it) and style it accordingly.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2xdgc30/1/)

JS

```
$('#proposal-check').on('change', function() {
  $('#signupCheck').addClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
#signupCheck.active:before {
    background-image: url("https://lh3.ggpht.com/OHBD2vcwNk80-q1P84NDmYjnwNmD8R-FjJagxvfcZhGHeRx6dNFX12afBL4e88nCra0=w300");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: No way. Both of us prefaced our answers with the same two things *in the same order* while writing our answers at the same time? Witchcraft!

Comment: @DerekStory No no, please leave it up as a reminder of BoltClock's humanity :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave it for the weird coincidence and my received upvote. I can't just go tossing away free points.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks to you both. You guys did basically post the answer at the same time and both worked. Not sure which answer to approve.

Comment: @Paul Approve his. Mine was a few seconds later.